# Why popup is not working?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using android google map there are different pins on map and nam and close button and a move button.popup is showing on map but when click another pin give exception as:-

```
10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3011)
10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:2900)
10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:2880)
10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):    at com.appstudioz.bidnear.map.BidNearItemizedOverlay.onTap(BidNearItemizedOverlay.java:85)
10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):    at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.onTap(ItemizedOverlay.java:453)
10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):    at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.onTap(OverlayBundle.java:83)
10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):    at com.google.android.maps.MapView$1.onSingleTapUp(MapView.java:356)
10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):    at com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:533)
10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):    at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:683)
10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:4609)
 10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1554)
10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1320)
 10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
 10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
 10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
  10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):  at  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
 10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
 10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
 10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
 10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
 10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1732)
 10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1267)
 10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2315)
  10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1705)
 10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
  10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
   10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
   10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
   10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
  10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
   10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):     at  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
  10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
   10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
   10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
   10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
   10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
   10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1560)
   10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1333)
   10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1732)
   10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1267)
    10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2315)
    10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1705)
   10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:4677)
   10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2394)
   10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:2054)
   10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
  10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
   10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
   10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
   10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
    10-06 22:17:17.080: E/AndroidRuntime(25156):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using this code as :- My webservice give number of object which have lat,long and showing on map as:-

```
MapController objmapcontroller;
    GeoPoint objgeopointp;
    double lat, lng;
    try {
        lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
        lng = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        lat = lng = 0;
    }
    objgeopointp = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
    objmapcontroller = objmapView.getController();

    // ---Add a location marker---


    // create and add an OverlayItem to the MyItemizedOverlay list
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(objgeopointp, title, snippet);
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    objmapcontroller.animateTo(objgeopointp);
    objmapcontroller.setZoom(16);
    // add the overlays to the map
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
    objmapView.invalidate();
```

And My overlay class is as in that class Ontap method whole class is as

```
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private Context mContext;
private MapView objmapview;
private View popUp;

public BidNearItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context ctx,MapView objmapview,View popUp) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    mContext =ctx;
    this.objmapview=objmapview;
    this.popUp=popUp;
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

public void clear() {
    mOverlays.clear();
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {

    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    Log.e("------size--",""+mOverlays.size());
    return mOverlays.size();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
     OverlayItem item=getItem(index);
      GeoPoint geo=item.getPoint();
      MapView.LayoutParams mapParams = new MapView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            geo,
            MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER);
     TextView objtxt = (TextView)popUp.findViewById(R.id.textup);
     TextView objtxt2 = (TextView)popUp.findViewById(R.id.text2);
     objtxt.setText(item.getTitle());
     objtxt2.setText(item.getSnippet());
     ImageView objimg = (ImageView)popUp.findViewById(R.id.bluebutton);
     ImageButton objbtn = (ImageButton)popUp.findViewById(R.id.closebutton);
     objbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("aclosehjdfd");
        }
    });
     objimg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("hohodshfsdh");
        }
    });
    objmapview.addView(popUp, mapParams);
    return true;
}
```

please anyone suggest me how I can achieve this goal thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the View popUp you are sending in to BidNearItemizedOverlay already has a parent. When you call addView(popUp, mapParams), you are trying to give it a second parent. This is not allowed. You must first detach it from its parent if you really want to use it. The easiest solution might be to create a new view based on the properties in popUp rather than use that actual view.

Or try:

```
((ViewGroup)popUp.getParent()).removeView(popUp);
```